# MVC Areas Overlayed Shared Layouts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout, asp.net-mvc-areas

I'm using Visual Studio to make an MVC App with sub-apps in Areas. In the root _Layout.cshtml I have a navbar-fixed-top that will have navigation to the different areas. I want this perpetuated on every single view. Then I modified the css to create a navbar-fixed-left where I will have navigation within just the particular area and that needs to be unique per area, but used on all views within that area.

So my question is, is there a way to use a shared layout within a shared layout so I don't redundantly copy and eventually screw up the top nav?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `RenderSection('leftNavigation', false)` in the html of your _layout page.

from the view that has left navigation you can fill the section

```
@section leftNavigation
{
    <ul>
        <a href="">Some line</a>
    </ul>
}
```

you can use the `@section` in the _viewStart.cshtml of the area is you have navigation that is valid for the complete area.

Comment: I didn't use sections, I used divs, but the rest of your answer made a lightbulb go off. I took the side navbar div out of the shared layout and have all _ViewStart.cshtml for root and areas start with Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml" and in that root layout I have the top navbar I want through the whole site. Then under that is where I build my side nav div with col-sm-3 col-md-2 in the ViewStarts, the main shared layout then has body content with col-offsets.

Comment: Actually, while what I did works, what you said seems to be more standard, and where I work we love standards so now I'm learning about partial views. Thank you again for your answer.